# Problems with simple_tag array values in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to pass an array to my template with a simple tag.
I created my module under app/templatetags/pages_navigation.py and in my opinion the code should be alright:

```
from django import template
from pages.models import Page

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name='links')
def pages_navigation():
  pages = Page.objects.all()
  links = [['Events','/']]

  for page in pages:
    links.append([page.title, '/'+page.url])

  return {'links':links}
```

In my template I try to access links like this:

```
<ul>
{% if links %}
  {% for link in links %}
    <a href="{{link.1}}"><li>{{link.0}}</li></a>
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <li>no pages found</li>
{% endif%}
</ul>
```

However, somehow it seems like links is always empty. 
When I tried the pages_navigation method in the python shell it worked fine..

Is it possible that you can't return arrays from simple tag methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

> Many template tags take a number of arguments -- strings or template variables -- and return a page_navigation after doing some processing

`simple tags` are for printing a piece of information, not assigning some result to a variable (a list in your case)

So, you would be better of using an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags):

```
@register.inclusion_tag('links.html')
def page_navigation(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    links = [['Events','/']]
    for page in pages:
        links.append([page.title, '/'+page.url])
    return {'links':links}
```

and creating a `links.html` file in your template directory:

```
<ul>
{% if links %}
    {% for link in links %}
    <a href="{{link.1}}"><li>{{link.0}}</li></a>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <li>no pages found</li>
{% endif%}
</ul>
```

and in your original template you can include this:

```
{% load pages_navigation %}
{% page_navigation %}
```

which will call the template tag, render it and insert it into your template

Comment: thx, i'm pretty sure that's it, i was looking on the inclusion tag, but i only included the load tag in the template and thought this would also already include the template. i'll try again tomorrow and post the result

Answer (score 4):

In new Django 1.4, you could use Assignment Tags https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-assignment-tags

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_links():
    return (('Events', '/'),) + tuple((p.title, '/'+p.url) for p in Page.objects.all())

{# in template #}
{% get_links as links %}
```

You could port it to your Django version if you like it.

Furthermore, if your page URLs is like /?page=2, you could try django-pagination http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pagination