# Django custom template-tag not rendered in loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My Custom tag:

```
# app/templatetags/ctags.py

def getgenre():
    genre = ["Test1", "Test2"]
    return genre

register.simple_tag(getgenre)
```

My html:

```
# app/templates/base.html

{% load ctags %}
<!-- {% getgenre %} -->
{% for genre in getgenre %}
    <li>{{genre}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This renders a blank page for me.
If I uncomment {% getgenre %}, django renders ["Test1", "Test2"] as expected.
I've tried countless variations of setting up my tag (including the non-simple_tag way) to no avail. I am simply unable to iterate over any value returned by one of my custom-tags.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Might be related to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860717/problems-with-simple-tag-array-values-in-django-template

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shoud use `assignment_tag` instead of `simple_tag`:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def getgenre():
    genre = ["Test1", "Test2"]
    return genre
```

And then in the template:

```
{% load ctags %}
{% getgenre as genre_list %}
{% for genre in genre_list %}
    <li>{{genre}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works! Awesome, thanks...should've read the documentation to the end -.-
Though I do think that they could've just mentioned the limitations of simple_tag...didn't find anything about that in the simple_tag section.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use simple_tags too because the docs say that assignment_tags are deprecated since 1.9, but I couldn't get those to work, while your solution does!

Answer (score 3):

**Custom tags write in the base.py in any app**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('templte/genre.html')
def getgenre():
    genre = ["Test1", "Test2"]
    return genre
```

**and then the template genre.html**

```
{% load ctags %}
{% for genre in genre_list %}
    <li>{{genre}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work for me. Neither does changing `genre_list` to `getgenre` or using `{% getgenre as genre_list %}`.

Comment: {% getgenre as genre_list %}

Comment: my way to code custom template tag in django, i create a folder inside the any apps , templatetags folder then create a base.py(it is common for all the custom tags, ) , here i code all tags then , i create a folder tag inside the templates , there i create a html page and coding after that , i just  load base in base.html[ main template in template folder ] after that , i incude the template tags function name inside the template, i hope you understood

Answer (score 1):

As `@register.assignment_tag` [has been removed after](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.9/#assignment-tag) **Django >= 1.9**. And like said in the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.9/#assignment-tag) *"The `simple_tag()` helper has gained this same ability"*. True but doesn't work with for loops at least in my case.

Instad of `register.simple_tag` use `register.filter` decorator [(reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797728/10364425).

```py
@register.filter
def getgenre(arg=None):
    genre = ["Test1", "Test2"]
    return genre
```

In template *(.html)*:

```html
{% load ctags %}
{% for genre in ""|genre_list %}
    <li>{{genre}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```